# How to parametrize setUpClass() in Python (2.7) unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am currently implementing a kind of table with interpolation between the values, boundary handling, etc. and want to write unit tests for it.

There is quite a set of possible scenarios e.g. the tables could have only one/multiple row(s)/column(s) and different boundary conditions. The tables in all of these scenarios should all pass the same set of unittests.

For now I am writing a base class for one of the cases and derive from it overriding the `setUpClass()` method. This is however tedious for testing all combinations.

Is there to generate the TestCase classes dynamically run them with different parameters.

When googling for the problem the best thing I found was overloading `load_tests()` and add all test methods one by one (which means setting up the objects prior to running each test method instead of once per scenario).

Comment: Why not write a class factory that creates subclasses of your main test class with a `setUpClass` based on the specific requirements of the scenario?

Comment: You can create paramterized test series using either [nose test generators](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators) or [pytest parametrize method](https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html).

Comment: @jonrsharpe This worked. The main reason I did not think about it, was that I did not know how to make PyCharm (or `unittest discover`) aware of the created classes. I now managed to do it using `load_tests()`.

Comment: @Tim if you've cracked it, you can write an answer to your own question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from @jonrsharpe I managed to do it.

My solution is to create the classes dynamically and then add them to the TestSuite using `load_tests`:

```
def create_test_case(testcase_name, scenario_data):
    class ScenarioTestCase(BaseTestCase):
        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls):
            cls.fillClassVariables(scenario_data)
    return_class = ScenarioTestCase
    return_class.__name__ = testcase_name #for separating the results
    return return_class


def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    list_scenario_names = [...]
    list_scenario_data = [...]

    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    tests = TestSuite()
    for scenario_name, scenario_data in zip(list_scenario_names, list_scenario_data):
        tests.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(
            create_test_case(scenario_name, scenario_data)))
    return tests
```

This way the TestCases are created dynamically with different parameters and listed separately in PyCharm's Test Runner Tab.

Comment: I might be inclined to have a list of tuples `[(scenario_name, scenario_data), ...]`, to keep the name and data together, but otherwise good job!

Answer (score 1):

Though this has an accepted answer, I want to document how to do this with subclassing, since it took me a long time to find the details of such a solution. In my case, the goal is for a TestCase class with several methods to have a class fixture (setting up files on the filesystem to test a cli tool), and vary this slightly in the parametrization.

```
# Inherit from object to not run this abstract class
class TemporaryFolderClassSetup(object):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        try:
            cls._root = tempfile.mkdtemp()
            # .. create some files here ...
            # allow subclasses to manipulate file tre
            cls.prepare_directory(cls._root)
        except Exception as e:
            cls.tearDownClass()
            raise

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        shutil.rmtree(cls._root)

    @classmethod
    def prepare_directory(cls, root):
        pass

    # test methods that will run in each subclass
    def testX():
        pass

# scenariotest, must inherit from superclass first, before unittest.TestCase)
class ScenarioTests(TemporaryFolderClassSetup, unittest.TestCase):

    # ... called by parent class
    @classmethod
    def prepare_directory(cls, root):
        pass

    # test only for this scenario
    def testY(self):
        pass
```